# How to get the mask average for multi-token masking?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

Following [this paper](https://aclanthology.org/2021.eacl-main.284/), I'm trying to implement how they calculated the average of the log probabilities for each entity (Section 3.3). More specifically, the score for each entity is calculated as the average of the log probabilities across its tokens.

I have a list of entities and some prompts:

```
my_entities = ['one', 'two', 'penicillin', 'chocolate', 'chocolates', 'potato', 'potatoes', 'kid', 'kiddies', 'alberta']
prompts = ['I like to eat [MASK]', '[MASK] are really good at playing soccer', '[MASK] is a drug']
```

The task is to find the `top_k` (e.g., top 3) entities that should fit instead of `[MASK]` for each prompt. The issue is that some entities are composed of multiple tokens:

```
import torch
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForMaskedLM
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model.eval()
for word in my_entities:
    word_id = tokenizer.encode(word, add_special_tokens=False)
    print(tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(word_id))
    print(word_id)
    print()
>>> 
['one']
[2028]

['two']
[2048]

['pen', '##ici', '##llin']
[7279, 28775, 21202]
[...]
```

If I understand correctly, in the paper, for each prompt they repeated the `[MASK]` token `k` times, where `k` is the number of tokens the model split some entity into: "We consider multitoken objects by including multiple [MASK] tokens in the templates":

```
for prompt in prompts:
    print('orignal prompt: ', prompt)
    for word in my_entities:
        word_id = tokenizer.encode(word, add_special_tokens=False)
        word_id_length = len(word_id)
        new_mask_string = '[MASK] ' * word_id_length
        modified_prompt = prompt.replace('[MASK]', new_mask_string).replace('  ', ' ')
        print('modified_prompt', modified_prompt)
>>>
orignal prompt:  I like to eat [MASK]
modified_prompt I like to eat [MASK] 
modified_prompt I like to eat [MASK] 
modified_prompt I like to eat [MASK] [MASK] [MASK]
```

But how can I get the average of the log probabilities for each of my entities so that I can take the top_k results?

Say I have one such modified prompt. I can get the model's hidden states at the masked position as follows:

```
sentence = '[MASK] [MASK] [MASK] are really good at playing soccer'
token_ids = tokenizer.encode(sentence, return_tensors='pt')
token_ids_tk = tokenizer.tokenize(sentence)
masked_position = (token_ids.squeeze() == tokenizer.mask_token_id).nonzero()
masked_pos = [mask.item() for mask in masked_position ]
with torch.no_grad():
    output = model(token_ids)
last_hidden_state = output[0].squeeze()
for mask_index in masked_pos:
    mask_hidden_state = last_hidden_state[mask_index]
    print(mask_hidden_state)

>>>
tensor([-9.3608, -9.2616, -9.2870,  ..., -8.5086, -8.2262, -8.5502])
tensor([-9.6831, -9.7911, -9.5848,  ..., -8.3435, -8.0961, -8.0973])
tensor([-6.2620, -6.3202, -6.1112,  ..., -5.9973, -5.6018, -5.8678])
```

But I'm not sure how to continue. The output I'm eventually looking for

```
my_entities = ['one', 'two', 'penicillin', 'chocolate', 'chocolates', 'potato', 'potatoes', 'kid', 'kiddies', 'alberta']
prompts = ['I like to eat [MASK]', '[MASK] are really good at playing soccer', '[MASK] is a drug']
scores = [[0.1, 0.3, 0.01...], [0.12, 0.23, 0.21...], [0.41, 0.3, 0.01...]]
```

Where `scores` is a list of length `len(prompts)`, where each sublist is of length `len(my_entities)`. That is, each sublist scores each entity for its fit in each modified prompt. Unless there's a more efficient approach to get the top_k entities for each prompt (e.g., instead of duplicating each prompt N times where N is the number of entities).

**Update: Adding an answer, but it's VERY slow**

I think I finally figured it out, but this is very slow and doesn't really use GPU as it iterates through each prompt one by one. I will accept an answer that can optimize this because at the current state I can't really use this code (too slow):

```
import torch
from transformers import AutoModelForMaskedLM, AutoTokenizer
import torch.nn as nn 

softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=0)
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
model = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased").to(device)
model.eval()

tokenized_masked_token = tokenizer.mask_token #"[MASK]"
entities = ["one", "two", "penicillin", "chocolate", "chocolates", "potato", "potatoes", "kids", "kiddies", "alberta", "alberta", "alberta", "chemistry", "absd"] * 1000
original_prompts = ["I like to eat [MASK]", "[MASK] are really good at playing soccer", "[MASK] is a drug"] * 3000
correct_answers = ["potatoes", "kids", "penicillin"] * 3000

top_k_value = 10
top_k_score = {'1':0, '5':0, '10':0} # dictionary to hold the results per model
prompts = [p.replace('[MASK]', tokenized_masked_token) for p in original_prompts] # replace the masked token from the original prompt with the corresponding tokenizer's masked token

ent_ids_lists = [tokenizer.encode(ent, add_special_tokens=False) for ent in entities] # get the ids for each entity
entity_lengths = [len(ent_ids_list) for ent_ids_list in ent_ids_lists] # get the length of each entity (number of tokens)
unique_entity_lengths = list(set(entity_lengths)) # get the set of different lengths
calculated_prompts_counter = 0

for idx, prompt in enumerate(prompts):
    if idx % 10 == 0:
        print(f'idx: {idx} out of {len(prompts)}')
    correct_answer = correct_answers[idx]
    probabilities_per_ent_length_dict = {} # a dictionary to hold the predicted probabilities per unique entity length -- so I won't need to duplicate each prompt len(entities) times, and just len(unique_entity_lengths) times   

    if prompt.count(tokenized_masked_token) != 1: # dont use prompts with more than 1 masking token because they break the prediction since we duplicate the masking token
        continue
    calculated_prompts_counter += 1 # count how many prompts we went over (not counting those with more than 1 masking token)

    # get length of each entity
    duplicated_prompt_list = [[prompt] * len(unique_entity_lengths)] # duplicate the prompt len(unique_entity_lengths) times (number of different entities length) -- JUST NEED TO DUPLICATE IT K TIMES, WHERE K IS THE DIFFERENT NUMBER OF ENTITY LENGTHS. SINCE THE PROBABILITIES WILL BE THE SAME FOR THE SAME PROMPT (THEY WILL ONLY DIFFER IF THERE ARE DIFFERENT NUMBER OF MASKED TOKENS)
    duplicated_prompt_flatten = [item for sublist in duplicated_prompt_list for item in sublist] # flatten
    masked_duplicated_prompts = [p.replace(tokenized_masked_token, tokenized_masked_token * l).replace('][', '] [') for p,l in zip(duplicated_prompt_flatten, unique_entity_lengths)] # replace each prompt masked token with the corresponding number of masked tokens
    
    for masked_duplicated_prompt, unique_entity_length in zip(masked_duplicated_prompts, unique_entity_lengths): 
        mask_hidden_states_lists = [] # a list to hold the hidden states of each masked token for each duplicated prompt
        token_ids = tokenizer.encode(masked_duplicated_prompt, return_tensors='pt') # tokenize the masked_duplicated_prompt
        if len(token_ids[0]) > 512: # truncate sequences that are longer than the context length
            token_ids = token_ids[0][:512].unsqueeze(0) # truncate

        token_ids_tk = tokenizer.tokenize(masked_duplicated_prompt)
        masked_position = (token_ids.squeeze() == tokenizer.mask_token_id).nonzero() # get positions of masked tokens
        masked_pos = [mask.item() for mask in masked_position] # get positions of masked tokens
        with torch.no_grad():
            output = model(token_ids.to(device)) # send input ids to the model to get predictions
        last_hidden_state = output[0].squeeze() # get last hidden states
        for mask_index in masked_pos: # masked_pos has a length of K, where K is the number of tokens the entity is split into
            mask_hidden_state = last_hidden_state[mask_index] # get the logits at the masked position
            mask_hidden_states_lists.append(softmax(mask_hidden_state)) # softmax to get probs from logits
        probabilities_per_ent_length_dict[unique_entity_length] = mask_hidden_states_lists # add the predicted probabilities for the specific entity length (each is a list of length K, where K is the number of tokens the entity is split into)
    
    entity_scores = [] # list to hold the scores for each entity -- we take the top_k from here. Each score is an average of the log of the probs
    entities_probs = [probabilities_per_ent_length_dict[ent_length] for ent_length in entity_lengths] # get probabilities per entity length (different length will have different number of mask tokens which will have different probabilities)
    for ent_ids_sublist_idx, ent_ids_sublist in enumerate(ent_ids_lists):
        tmp_score_list = []
        ent_id_sublist_len = len(ent_ids_sublist)
        for ent_len_idx in range(ent_id_sublist_len):
            ent_log_prob = torch.log(entities_probs[ent_ids_sublist_idx][ent_len_idx][ent_ids_sublist[ent_len_idx]])
            tmp_score_list.append(ent_log_prob)
        entity_scores.append(torch.tensor(tmp_score_list).mean())
    topk_entity_sublist_indices = torch.topk(torch.tensor(entity_scores), top_k_value).indices
    top_k_entity_ids = [ent_ids_lists[idx] for idx in topk_entity_sublist_indices] #torch.index_select(torch.tensor(ent_ids_lists), 0, topk_entity_sublist_indices)
    top_k_entity_strings = tokenizer.batch_decode(top_k_entity_ids)
    
    if correct_answer in top_k_entity_strings[:1]:
        top_k_score['1'] += 1
    if correct_answer in top_k_entity_strings[:5]:
        top_k_score['5'] += 1
    if correct_answer in top_k_entity_strings:
        top_k_score['10'] += 1                

print(f'top 1 accuracy: {top_k_score["1"]/calculated_prompts_counter}')
print(f'top 5 accuracy: {top_k_score["5"]/calculated_prompts_counter}')
print(f'top 10 accuracy: {top_k_score["10"]/calculated_prompts_counter}')
```